# Nested ul show on anchor click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a site structured like so :

When I click the "add-info" the ul does not show, Not quite sure what to do with it to get it to show?

```
<ul>
    <li>Liebherr LHM 600 Mobile Harbour Crane. <a class="add-info" href="#">Find out more</a>
        <ul class="hidden-list">
            <li>Liebherr LHM 600 Mobile Harbour Crane. SWL of 208 Ton and capable of lifting 53.7 ton at 58 meters radius. Can be used for bulk container loading/unloading with our Bromma container handler attachment. Maximum hoisting height above quay of 59 metres.</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Liebherr LR1300 Crawler Crane. <a class="add-info" href="#">Find out more</a>
        <ul class="hidden-list">
            <li>Coming December 2014 Liebherr LR1300 Crawler Crane. Can be configured to lift 300.5 ton and can be configured to a maximum radius of 80 metres. Can be fitted with a leader rig attachment and Bruce 16 ton piling hammer for piling.</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Sennebogen 6130 Crawler Crane. <a class="add-info" href="#">Find out more</a>
        <ul class="hidden-list">
            <li>Sennebogen 6130 Crawler Crane. Can be configured to lift 136 ton and has a maximum radius of 42 metres.</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Zoomlion RT55 Rough Terrain Crane. <a class="add-info" href="#">Find out more</a>
        <ul class="hidden-list">
            <li>RT55 Rough Terrain Crane. SWL of 54.88 ton and a maximum working radius radius of 41 metres. A main jib head height of 34 metres but also comes complete with a telescopic fly jib that can increase the head height up to a height of 54 metres and can be offset from 0 to 40 degrees.</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Scheuerle 6 axel SPMT modular trailers complete with Z350 power pack units. <a class="add-info" href="#">Find out more</a>
        <ul class="hidden-list">
            <li>Scheuerle 6 axel SPMT modular trailers complete with Z350 power pack units. With a SWL of 48 ton per axel can be supplied in a vast array of different configurations.</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Forklifts <a class="add-info" href="#">Find out more</a>
        <ul class="hidden-list">
            <li>Various sizes of forklifts available from 2.5 ton up to 32 ton.</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What I'd like to do is on the "add-info" click in jQuery, Show the ul.hidden-list, SlideDown or whatever effect, As long as it shows.

I have created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vog8bsLc/)

My current jQuery code :

```
$('.add-info').click(function() {

    $(this).children('ul.hidden-list').slideToggle();

    return false;
});
```

Comment: I would suggest you to use chromes console in this kind of situations. Just put a breakpoint to the line starting with `$(this)...` then on console write your selectors, and see what is it returning then you can improve or fix your code much more easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your markup `<ul>` element is placed as a next element to `<a>` and not as a direct descendant, so [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) (or [`.siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)) method should be used:

```
$('.add-info').click(function() {
    $(this).next('ul.hidden-list').slideToggle();

    return false;
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/vog8bsLc/1/